# How to populate 2<weeks<9 from javascript to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="test">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>

 str="<tr><td>3<weeks<=9</td></tr>";
 $('#test tbody').html('str');

</script>
```

Output is coming:
3 as one column in table because '<' will treat as html tag. How to fix this. I want to populate 3< weeks<=9 in table

Comment: Adding to answers there are a lot of other such **HTML entities** such as [listed here](http://character-code.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`&lt;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)**(or **[`&#60;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)**) for `lessthan(<)` symbol

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  str = "<tr><td>3&lt;weeks&lt;=9</td></tr>";
  //            --^--    --^--
  $('#test tbody').html(str);
</script>
```

Refer : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

---

Or you can use jQuery to get done that job by generating elements using jQuery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $('<tr>', {
    html: $('<td>', {
      text: '3<weeks<=9'
    })
  }).appendTo('#test tbody');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in this case is escape the **'<'** character so that it is not treated as html. The Escape character HTML code for **'<'** in this case is **'&lt;'**. Hope this helps you

Comment: thank you 4castle was just editing the comment myself